# VARCHAR Length is -1 in dbeaver. Why?

Tags: sql-server, dbeaver

I am using the MSSQL database and using dbeaver as a Database Manager. I found a field declared as a VARCHAR and has a length of ( -1 ) what does it stand for?

[image]

dbeaver version is 7.3.2.202101032114. the latest one

[image]

Comment: Could it be a VARCHAR(max) field?

Comment: Looks like an issue with the DBeaver, this has been fixed in V 7.3.2

Comment: in the model definition is a TEXT field @Mark Rotteveel

Comment: Is it *really* a `text` column, @Poode ? That data type was deprecated 16 years ago... You should have *long* started using `varchar(MAX)` by now. I also, however, am skeptical it is a `text` column, as `text` column's `max_length` value is *not* `-1` (it's `16`).

Comment: I mean in the model in js file I am using sequelize and bhind the scene tedious js is used @Larnu

Comment: That has nothing, however, to do with the database backend, @Poode ; that's the frontend. DBeaver is reporting `-1` as that's how SQL Server denotes `MAX` length; as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MAX` datalengths are defined as `-1` in the system objects. Some applications therefore will report the length as `-1`, instead of `MAX`.

For example:

```sql
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable (varcharColMAX varchar(MAX),
                            nvarcharColMAX nvarchar(MAX),
                            varbinaryColMAX varbinary(MAX),
                            varcharCol10 varchar(10),
                            nvarcharCol10 nvarchar(10),
                            varbinaryCol10 varbinary(10));
SELECT c.name,
       c.max_length
FROM sys.tables t
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.[name] = 'TestTable';

DROP TABLE dbo.TestTable;
```

Which outputs:

```
name             max_length
---------------- ----------
varcharColMAX    -1
nvarcharColMAX   -1
varbinaryColMAX  -1
varcharCol10     10
nvarcharCol10    20
varbinaryCol10   10
```

*Note that `nvarcharCol10` has a length of `20` as `max_length` reports the size in bytes, and a single `nvarchar` character is 2 bytes in length (2 * 10 = 20).*

Comment: Yes you are right in my database dumb I found that  
[Comment] [varchar](max) 
Thanks Larnu